# C# - Using StandardInput and StandardOutput to Run Commands Against a Switch and Reading/Responding to Results

Tags: c#

I know this has to do with my limited understanding of using streams, so any direction that will help solidify my knowledge in this area would be helpful.

I’m using a terminal process to send plink commands and SSH into a switch of mine. I know it’s not the most eloquent way of doing this, but it’s what I have for now (I was having trouble figuring out how to get SSHNet to run multiple commands against the switch in one session). My main problem is that I’m trying to run multiple commands to the switch and react to the output. For example, after creating the cmd.exe process and logging in, I send the following command:

```
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(“sh version | i cat3k_caa-univeralk”);
```

I’d like to take the output of that command and do something with it, specifically write the results to a richtextbox that I have, and if the version doesn’t look right, run another command against the switch in response, write the results to the richtextbox, and then continue on sending commands to the switch until I’m finished, allowing this back-and-forth, reading the output from the switch, and then writing back to the switch.

However, every time I’ve attempted to try this with something like:

```
while (!cmd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{ do stuff here }
```

And then attempt to try a response command or even just my next command like:

```
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(“sh version | i Configuration register”);
```

It never gets there, it just hangs on the previous read from output command and doesn’t continue. I have a feeling it has to do with using Asynchronous commands or that I should be using them, but I’ve looked at the Microsoft documents and it just isn’t clicking in my head how I should be using it.

Here’s a snippet of my code so you can have a better idea of what I’m doing. Any help in making me understand how this should work would make me extremely appreciative.

```
 private void connectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            consoleRichTxtBx.Clear();

            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\";
            cmd.Start();

            this.Text = GetDNSNameFromIP(cmd).ToUpper();
            cmd.Close();

            cmd.Start();
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("plink " + ipTxtBx.Text + " -ssh -l " + usrTxtBx.Text + " -pw " + pwdTxtBx.Text);
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ter len 0");
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("sh version | i cat3k_caa-universalk");
            checkVersionNumber(cmd);
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("sh version | i Configuration register");
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("sh run | i scp server");
            more commands and parsing stuff;
```

And the code for that checkVersionNumber method where I'm trying to read the output:

```
private void checkVersionNumber(Process cmd)
        {
            while (!cmd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string lineread = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                doing stuff with output
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help/insight you can provide.

Comment: You're right, this is going to need async reads and writes rather than synchronous ones. YOull probably Also need to read from std error. Establish async read/write paths. Manage program flow by setting an enumeration value before you do your write, so that when the async read gets something, it knows what stage the command flow is at and what to do next

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard, so I've been playing around with this, and I'm not sure if I'm approaching this wrong, but I'm not seeing any way around needing to write to the process's streamwriter again after disposing it.  The data doesn't seem to be written to the StandardOutput until the streamwriter is disposed/closed, so then after reading it, I can't reopen the streamwriter again to add new commands for additional output. Is there a way around this, or a better way of approaching this that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Scratch that... it dawned on me that I also needed to be using async writes (just as you told me), and learn how that works... I think after experimenting with it in some example test cases, I've finally figured out how to get this all to work. Thank you for your insight.